# weave cni is not assigning ip address to weave bridge with in the node cidr in k8s

Tags: kubernetes, weave, cni

I'm trying to bootstrap the k8s cluster using weave as cni plugin which was originally configured without --pod-cidr and weave plugin

```
root@kube1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# kubectl get no
NAME    STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kube1   Ready    master   31m   v1.18.2
kube2   Ready    <none>   30m   v1.18.2
kube3   Ready    <none>   31m   v1.18.2
root@kube1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d#
```

So i have done the cleanup using the below commands

```
 kubectl drain kube2 --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
 kubectl drain kube3 --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
 kubectl drain kube1 --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets

 kubectl delete no kube1 kube2 kube3

 kubeadm reset

 curl -L git.io/weave -o /usr/local/bin/weave
 chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/weave
 kubeadm reset
 weave reset --force

 rm /opt/cni/bin/weave-*

 iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
 iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
 iptables -t nat -F
 iptables -t mangle -F
 iptables -F
 iptables -X
 systemctl restart docker
```

i have ensured the weave bridge interface was deleted on all 3 nodes and re initiated the cluster

```
  kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address=192.168.56.101 --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.100.0.0/16
```

I have ensured  the node-cidr was allocated to worker nodes(pod-cidr - 10.244.0.0./16) as below

```
root@kube1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# kubectl get no kube2 -o yaml|grep -i podCIDR|grep -i 24
  podCIDR: 10.244.2.0/24

root@kube1:/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d# kubectl get no kube3 -o yaml|grep -i podCIDR|grep -i 24
  podCIDR: 10.244.1.0/24
```

After i have created the weave pod's ,i was expecting to see the weave bridge interface ip in 10.244.* but it created with default weave configuration (10.32.0.1) it seems

```
root@kube2:/etc/kubernetes# ifconfig weave
weave: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1376
        inet 10.32.0.1  netmask 255.240.0.0  broadcast 10.47.255.255
        inet6 fe80::187b:63ff:fe5c:a2ae  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1a:7b:63:5c:a2:ae  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
```

Is there anything i have missed to clean up? or is it weave plugins default behaviour?

Comment: you had a different cni before? what was it?

Comment: befor also same weave only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Weave Net uses its own IP allocator, which can be configured via the environment variable `IPALLOC_RANGE`. [Link to docs](https://www.weave.works/docs/net/latest/kubernetes/kube-addon/#-changing-configuration-options)

If you change the CNI config on each node to use a different IPAM plugin, e.g. ["host-local"](https://github.com/containernetworking/plugins/tree/master/plugins/ipam/host-local)
 you can probably get that to do exactly what you tried to do.

Comment: in that case,flannel is using host-local ipam?